# How to fire INotifyPropertyChanged handler when I change ComboBox's selected item?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, inotifypropertychanged

I'm trying to bind a `ComboBox` to an `ObservableCollection<MyType>` but it's not working as I expect. When I create an instance of `ComboData`, e.g.

```
ComboData = new ObservableCollection<MyType>();
```

and add data to it, e.g.

```
ComboData.Add(new MyType(string.Format("{0}", i.ToString()), i));
```

I can see that the `Value` property of `MyType` is being set and the `PropertyChangedEventHandler` event handler executes. This is correct functionality.

The problem is when I select a different item in the `ComboBox` later. I expect to see `Value` being set again and firing the event handler, but nothing happens. However, I can see that the property's getter is being fired and returning `_value`.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

`MyType` is defined as:

```
public class MyType : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MyType(string key, int value)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }

    public string Key { get; set; }
    private int _value;
    public int Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            if (_value != value)
            {
                _value = value;

                OnPropertyChanged("Value");
            }
        }
    }

    internal void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }

    private void IntegerItem_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // this never executes *after* the ComboBox has been populated!!!
    }

}
```

The User Control's XAML is:

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cboItems"
      DisplayMemberPath="Key"
      SelectedValuePath="Value"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ComboData}">
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

And the code behind for the User Control is

```
public partial class ComboBoxControl : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyType> ComboData { get; set; }

    public ComboBoxControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ComboData = new ObservableCollection<MyType>();
        int min = 0;
        int max = 10;
        for (int i = min; i <= max; i++)
        {
            ComboData.Add(new MyType(string.Format("{0}", i.ToString()), i));
        }

        cboItems.DataContext = this;            
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to fire the event handler when I change the selected item in the `ComboBox`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting a different option in your combobox isn't changing any of the items in ComboData, it's just changing the selected item, so it won't use the setter in MyType.  It uses the getter to retrieve the value to display.

The ComboBox has a SelectedItemChanged event which will trigger when a new item is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `CollectionView` class, which has a CurrentChanged event.. You can bind CollectionView to your ComboBox. So when selecteditem change.. you can get value from CollectionViewMember.CurrentItem in CurrentChangedEvent